# OpenGl framebuffer performance problems

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, jogl, framebuffer

I am currently trying to create a simple lighting engine for my game developed in JAVA. I am using a framebuffer object to draw images of the light sources onto an ambient color and combine it with the previously rendered scene to get a simple lighting. Everything works nicely except that the framerate gets cut in half, from a steady 60 FPS to a fluctuating 30 FPS.

Here is my current approach:

(This is done in my main display loop)

```
        int[] params1 = new int[1];
        gl2.glGenTextures(1, params1, 0);
        int textureID = params1[0];
        gl2.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
        gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
        gl2.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA8, Game.RES_WIDTH, Game.RES_HEIGHT, 0, GL.GL_BGRA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

        int[] params2 = new int[1];
        gl2.glGenFramebuffers(1, params2, 0);
        int frameBufferID = params2[0];
        gl2.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID);
        gl2.glClear(0);
        gl2.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID, 0);

        DrawUtils.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT, getAmbientLight()); 

        gl2.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_DST_ALPHA);    

        //Code for drawing the light sources here...

        gl2.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        gl2.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_DST_COLOR, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        gl2.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl2.glPushMatrix();
        gl2.glColor3f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
        gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        gl2.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl2.glNormal3i(0, 0, 1);
        gl2.glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
        gl2.glVertex2i(0, 0);
        gl2.glTexCoord2i(1, 0);
        gl2.glVertex2i(0 + Game.WIDTH, 0);
        gl2.glTexCoord2i(1, 1);
        gl2.glVertex2i(Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);
        gl2.glTexCoord2i(0, 1);
        gl2.glVertex2i(0, Game.HEIGHT);
        gl2.glEnd();
        gl2.glPopMatrix();
        gl2.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        gl2.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        gl2.glDeleteTextures(1, params1, 0);
        gl2.glDeleteFramebuffers(1, params2, 0);
```

Comment: You should profile your code to see where the slowdown is.

Comment: It's `gl2.glGenFramebuffers(1, params2, 0);`

Comment: Would it be possible to generate the framebuffers you need ahead of time and re-use them each time through the loop, then?

Comment: The bad news is `glGenFramebuffers (...)` does not actually do anything. It returns the first unused name and reserves it, nothing more. This means whatever technique you used to determine that your bottleneck was this function is wrong. More than likely, `gl2.glBindFramebuffer (...)` is your actual bottleneck - that is the only API call with any measurable overhead anywhere near `glGenFramebuffers (...)`. That will actually create the FBO after you reserve it, which can have appreciable overhead. If your bottleneck legitimately is `glGenFramebuffers (...)`, then JOGL is doing something wrong.

Comment: I am curious though, why are you giving `glClear (...)` a bitmask **0**? You are telling it to clear nothing. While this will not set any erroneous bits, and thus will not generate an error, it is also completely meaningless.

Comment: I was simply commenting out, I didn't profile. If its not `gl2.glGenFramebuffers` then moving it out of my loop wouldn't make any difference right? How can games have multiple render passes then? @Andon M. Coleman The `glClear(0)` was a suggestion to solve performance issues but sadly it was only for android. Just forgot about removing it again.

Comment: You do not have to throw out your FBO after every pass. No shipping game should do this, in fact. You can create the FBO and the texture necessary for storage of your pass when you initialize whatever is responsible for requiring the pass, the same way you persistently store VBOs. Creating a new FBO / texture every pass is crazy, dynamic resource allocation like this is a great way to miss deadlines in real-time software... or to put this in simpler terms, cause FPS fluctuation. You want the amount of work that needs to be done per-frame to be consistent and re-using resources helps a lot.

Comment: Consider the case where allocating memory for your texture requires `O(N)` time to find a free location (in the best-case, with no fragmentation), where N is related to the number of textures already allocated. In this case, as your program runs and you load more and more textures, each pass will take longer and longer to allocate memory (even if the amount of memory requested never changes). This is an over-simplification, but it shows why you want to keep resources around for core parts of your render process rather than freeing and re-acquiring them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the framebuffer creation out of my loop did solve the problem:

```
public void init(GL2 gl2)
{
    int[] params1 = new int[1];
    gl2.glGenTextures(1, params1, 0);
    textureID = params1[0];
    gl2.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_NEAREST);
    gl2.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA8, Game.RES_WIDTH, Game.RES_HEIGHT, 0, GL.GL_BGRA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    int[] params2 = new int[1];
    gl2.glGenFramebuffers(1, params2, 0);
    frameBufferID = params2[0];
    gl2.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferID);
    gl2.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL2.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID, 0);

    gl2.glBindFramebuffer(GL2.GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```